# Script to take data from excel to Ansys for applying pressure value

Tags: python, excel, ironpython, ansys

I have excel tabular data of force for different faces/locations. I wanted to create the pressure tab in Ansys workbench and apply force data from reading cells from excel, but it shows following error.
Invalid quantity string: CC1[MPa]

Following code I used to read data:-

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel")
import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel as Excel
ex = Excel.ApplicationClass()
ex.Visible = True
workbook = ex.Workbooks.Open(r"D:\Work\Extra_Work_IMP\1_TMF_macro\Input.xlsx")
worksheet=workbook.worksheets("LC1")
#Define Key ranges in the Workbook
#C1 is location and CC1 is force value
C1 = worksheet.Range["A4"].Text
CC1 = worksheet.Range["B4"].Value
NS= ExtAPI.DataModel.Project.Model.AddNamedSelection()
NS.Name= C1
named_selection=DataModel.GetObjectsByName(C1)
Pressure=DataModel.AnalysisList[0]
my_pressure_1=Pressure.AddPressure ()
my_pressure_1.Location=named_selection[0]
my_pressure_1.Magnitude.Output.DiscreteValues=[Quantity('CC1' '[MPa]')]
```

Comment: Excel error? Ansys error or Python error?

Comment: Isn't there a comma missing:
`my_pressure_1.Magnitude.Output.DiscreteValues=[Quantity('CC1', '[MPa]')]`

Answer (score 0):

'Invalid quantity string: CC1[MPa]' means that you are actually writing that string directly in your Ansys application, so you are passing the string 'CC1' instead of the actual value of CC1. Instead of:

```
my_pressure_1.Magnitude.Output.DiscreteValues=[Quantity('CC1' '[MPa]')]
```

try

```
my_pressure_1.Magnitude.Output.DiscreteValues=[Quantity(str(CC1) '[MPa]')]
```

By the way, introducing information like that to the Quantity function does not work for me. I suggest you to use it in as recommended in the Help Documentation, with a 'space' separation between the value and the units:

```
my_pressure_1.Magnitude.Output.DiscreteValues=[Quantity(str(CC1)+' [MPa]')]
```